# What manga is this picture of a melting boy from?

Tags: domestic-na-kanojo

I know it's not much to go on, but if you could let me know what manga this is from I'd be much obliged.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this picture from?

Comment: A friend of mine came across it a while ago but couldn't find the source again ^^'

Comment: Looks like Domestic na Kanojo, but I should check

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It actually was [Domestic na Kanojo](http://myanimelist.net/manga/70941/Domestic_na_Kanojo), as I first thought, to be precise it was taken from chapter 22.

This is the full image:
[image]
Synopsis

> Tonight, Natsuo loses his virginity. His partner? Her name is Rui and he just met her today after school. She's the one that brought up this whole situation, stating that she wanted to simply gain the knowledge about sex. She does not want to start a relationship, nor does she care about Natsuo. Afterwards, Natsuo feels guilty for losing his virginity to a girl he doesn't even particularly like. Mostly, it makes him feel like he betrayed his crush to his high school teacher: Hina. A quirky love triangle story unfolds as Natsuo, Rui, and Hina all end up becoming part of the same family!

Comment: I think there are better rom-com Manga around,  but it's still readable.

Comment: It actually was chapter 22, I've edited the answer